# javascript find sum of array values

Tags: javascript

I have a select list of salaries and I am attempting to find the sum of all array values greater than the value selected from the list. I am unable to get my code to output the sum.

```js
salaries = [59360, 37012, 30301, 39738, 39169, 52832, 42132, 41220, 36901, 54497, 53108, 32553, 43023, 51505, 31499];

document.getElementById('go').onclick = function() {
  var numberFilter = document.getElementById('filter').value;
  total = 0;
  for (index = 0; index < salaries.length; index++) {
    if (salaries[index] > numberFilter) {
      total = total + salaries[index];
      document.getElementById('result').value = total;
    };
  };
};
```

```html
<select id='filter' name=''>
  <option value = '0'>0</option>
  <option value = '30000'>30000</option>
  <option value = '35000'>35000</option>
  <option value = '40000'>40000</option>
  <option value = '45000'>45000</option>
  <option value = '50000'>50000</option>
  <option value = '55000'>55000</option>
</select>

<button id='go' class=''>GO</button>
<input id='result' name='' value='' class=''>
<input id='count' name='' value='' class=''>
<script src='js/javascript 15.js'></script>
```

Comment: What is `numbers`?

Comment: Did you mean to say "salaries" instead of "numbers"?  (@Ssswift asked what I was originally going to ask :)

Comment: @theGleep yes that is a mistake, its supposed to be salaries

Comment: Why do you write to the DOM inside the loop? Regardless of "if it works", that's bad style. Finish the loop, then write your result. In additon, about your example, the if condition makes no sense given your example code. There also is no use for your `numberFilter ` variable anywhere in sight.

Comment: `> 30` so shouldn't that be the value of the select?

Comment: @epascarello yeah thats supposed to be the value selected. would it be numberFilter that goes in there?

Comment: You are missing var in front of salaries and total. should be var total = 0; and var salaries = ["etc..."];

Comment: It seems to be working fine since you fixed the `numers` typo.

Comment: @Barmar really? Im still not getting it to run

Comment: Click on Run Code Snippet, select 30000 from the menu, click Go, it displays 644850 in the result input.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like there's a few things that need to be changed:

- `numbers` needs to be changed to `salaries` (as numbers is not a defined variable in your code)
- `30` needs to be changed to `numberFilter`, since your trying to find the sum of all the array values greater than `numberFilter`, not `30`
- You only need to update the result once: after the sum has been calculated. You don't need to update the result during every iteration of the for loop. Updating during every iteration would still work, but it is neither necessary nor efficient.
- Better spacing

So your code would become

```
salaries = [59360, 37012, 30301, 39738, 39169, 52832, 42132, 41220, 36901, 54497, 53108, 32553, 43023, 51505, 31499];

document.getElementById('go').onclick = function () {

    var numberFilter = document.getElementById('filter').value;

    total = 0;

    for (index = 0; index < salaries.length; index++) {

        if (salaries[index] > numberFilter) {

            total = total + salaries[index];

        };

    };

document.getElementById('result').value = total;

};
```

Comment: @see see thats what I thought, but when I went to run it, it still does not show up in my results textbox. I dont get any numbers in there

Comment: @Astonishing Ah, I had forgotten to change `numbers` to `salaries` in the for loop condition and the body of the if statement in addition to the if statement condition. I have edited my answer accordingly, and the code should now be functional.

Answer (score 1):

```
let salaries = [59360, 37012, 30301, 39738, 39169, 52832, 42132, 41220, 36901, 54497, 53108, 32553, 43023, 51505, 31499]
```

You could first filter out the numbers that you're interested in.

For example, numbers that are greater than **30000**

```
const numberFilter = 30000
let salaries = salaries.filter(salary => salary > numberFilter)
```

Then sum them:

```
const salariesSum = salaries.reduce((prev, current) => prev + current)
```

Or oneliner:

```
const numberFilter = 30000
const salariesSum = salaries.filter(salary => salary > numberFilter).reduce((a, b) => a + b)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just need to reference your `salaries` array instead of `numbers`, as `numbers` is not declared. Then you need to add some comparison logic to get whatever is greater than the filter number.

```
var salaries = [59360, 37012, 30301, 39738, 39169, 52832, 42132, 41220, 36901, 54497, 53108, 32553, 43023, 51505, 31499];

document.getElementById('go').onclick = function () {

   var numberFilter = document.getElementById('filter').value;

   var total = 0;
   for (index = 0; index < salaries.length; index++) {

      if (salaries[index] > numberFilter) {
         total = total + salaries[index];
      };

   };
   //Write the result after the loop is complete
   document.getElementById('result').value = total;
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) Array prototypes to create the sum. You also need to attach an event listener to the `select`, otherwise your script will only ever run once with the initial value of the `select`.

```js
var salaries = [59360, 37012, 30301, 39738, 39169, 52832, 42132, 41220, 36901, 54497, 53108, 32553, 43023, 51505, 31499];

document.getElementById('filter').addEventListener('change', event => {
  var filteredSalaries = salaries.filter(salary => { return salary > event.target.value });
  var sum = filteredSalaries.reduce( (salary, total) => { return total + salary}, 0);
  
  console.log('sum', sum);
  console.log('salaries greater than filter', filteredSalaries);
  document.getElementById('result').value = sum;
});
```

```html
<select id='filter' name=''>
  <option value = '0'>0</option>
  <option value = '30000'>30000</option>
  <option value = '35000'>35000</option>
  <option value = '40000'>40000</option>
  <option value = '45000'>45000</option>
  <option value = '50000'>50000</option>
  <option value = '55000'>55000</option>
</select>

<input id="result" value="" />
```